# using source_gen how to call a generator using an extended annotation?

Tags: dart

using [source_gen](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/source_gen) package how can I call a generator using an extended annotation?

Let's say I have next generator:

```
class MyAnnotationGenerator extends GeneratorForAnnotation<MyAnnotation> {
const MyAnnotationGenerator();

Future<String> generateForAnnotatedElement(ClassElement element, Serializable annotation, BuildStep buildStep) async {
...
}
```

I would like to call `MyAnnotationGenerator` for every annotation that extends `MyAnnotation`. For example:

```
class MyAnnotation {
  const MyAnnotation();
}

class MyExtendedAnnotation extends MyAnnotation {
  const MyExtendedAnnotation();
}
```

so every time the annotation `MyExtendedAnnotation` is used I would like to call `MyAnnotationGenerator`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can with `GeneratorForAnnotation`.

You could implement the `Generator` interface and do the checks yourself though.

Answer (score 1):

`GeneratorForAnnotation` does not check extended annotation.

You could write your own generator and do the check, 
if you don't want to, you will have to set a generator by annotation class.

```
class MyAnnotationGenerator extends GeneratorForAnnotation<MyAnnotation>
class MyExtendAnnotationGenerator extends GeneratorForAnnotation<MyExtendedAnnotation>

new GeneratorBuilder(const [
     const MyAnnotationGenerator(),
     const MyExtendAnnotationGenerator()
   ])
```